# How to authenticate two type of authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.1?

Tags: authentication, .net-core

ASP .NET Core(2.1) Web API authenticate LDAP users(intranet app - windows authentication ) and external tool requests against application key.

How to authenticate two type of authentication in ASP.NET Core 2.1?